# Smallrye Kafka producer inside a lambda - TimeoutException

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I am running a Smallrye Kafka producer inside a Kotlin lambda. The problem is, that I'm getting a TimeoutException most of the time I try to send messages to the Kafka broker (running in Aiven). I read, that this is possibly an issue with the producer's timeout configuration, but I'd like to get more information on how to try and configure the `request.timeout.ms` of the producer, since information on how to do that for the smallrye connector is very limited.[image: The application.yaml config][image: producer's code]

[image: Exceptions from cloudwatch]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Kafka client configuration on the channel config directly, such as:

```yaml
[...]
mp:
  messaging:
    outgoing:
      talos-dmex-dmexSubmitted:
        request:
          timeout:
            ms: 10000
```

Comment: I actually just saw, that the milliseconds, that passed after the batch was created were 316754, so about 5.5 minutes. However, the test I made was with only 2 messages. I'm wondering, if it doesn't have anything to do with the batch size. However, when I test producing only 1 message, then around every 1 out of 3 attempts is successful. I am a bit confused, to say the least.